# Unable to find django in pycharm community IDE

Tags: python, django

I am getting started to **django**. I created a basic project using the below in windows powershell :

```
django-admin startproject project1
```

This create the project structure, then I opened the project in pycharm , but looks like django module is not recognized.

The below lines in urls.py are complaining - Unresolved reference django

Also, when I run `manage.py`, below error is thrown :

```
C:\Users\611834094\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/611834094/project1/manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/611834094/project1/manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/611834094/project1/manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Do you have more than 1 python versions installed?

Comment: No Harsha, I am using python 3.6.3 which is the only version installed.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/250442/django-installed-but-cant-import-django-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got resolved after switching to system interpreter instead of using the virtual environment.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to install Django for Python first.

Try running `pip install Django` in your command line (this install Django using Pip, the Python package manager), and then running `manage.py` again.

Comment: Still got the same issue

Comment: if `django-admin startproject project1` is creating project meaning django installed successfully

Comment: @setushwetank hmm perhaps you could have a look at luc's answer below on setting the correct interpreter in PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

First try installing Django first `pip install Django`

and
To import existing Django Project :

Open myproject as your project and then go to PyCharm -> Preferences... -> Django, Enable Django Support and then choose your Django project root, settings file and manage script.

For creating and running Django Project Read this [doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/step-4-creating-and-running-your-first-django-project.html)

this is for Professional edition however for community edition read this [doc](http://ruddra.com/2015/09/18/how-to-configure-django-tornado-in-pycharm-community-edition/)

Hope this helps you! :)

Comment: Thanks for reply Abdullah. Thing is I don't get an option to create project type - Django. I am using community edition of pycharm. Not sure whether this option comes in community edition

Comment: Yes you are right the option project type - Django comes only in Professional edition to use Django in community edition read this [link] (http://ruddra.com/2015/09/18/how-to-configure-django-tornado-in-pycharm-community-edition/) I will modify my answer!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should install django first. If you are using python2.X. You can only install django below version2.0, like this:

```
pip install --upgrade django==1.9
```

Otherwise, you can install the newest version(2.0)

```
pip install Django
```

After that you can check the django version by this:

```
python -m django --version
```

If it shows the version, then you are set and ready to go!

Comment: PS C:\Users\611834094> python -m django --version
2.0.2  .. It shows the version , still doesn't work in pycharm

Comment: It seems that your pycharm can not find the python packages, you can check it like this, click File->Settings->Project:XXX->Project Interpreter. Then check whether you have installed the django module. I guess you must be using the vitural env, right? And the virtual env interpreter has not installed django.

Comment: Hello Alex, I followed the above steps , I found Django package (D in caps). While installing I get the below error :Collecting Django

  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03A897D0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/django/ Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Django

Comment: hmm, It seems the pycharm can not install packages through IDE. In fact, you have already install Django to you local python. Why not switch the interpreter of your project to you local Python3.X or Python2.X instead of using virtual env?

Comment: I have installed cx_Oracle through IDE before, so ideally installing package should be fine.

Comment: This issue got resolved by switching to system interpreter instead of virtual environment. Can you pls explain what is the difference between the two.

Comment: Based on my understanding, python virtualenv is kind of virtual execution environment, it is a isolated environment compared with your local python execution. Just like a sandbox. You can create an execution environment with different configuration. For example you have two projects, one of them needs django1.9 and the other one needs django2.0. So you can create two virtualenv for two projects and install different django. If you use local python environment, you can only install one django, right? So this is the typical usage of virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes PyCharm is using the wrong python interpreter.

You can check the one which is used in `Preferences > Project > Project Interpreter`

Make sure it corresponds to the virtualenv of your project. If not, you can change the Python interpreter by browsing to the right one.

Comment: I created a virtualenv of my project, still the same issue persists. pycharm cannot resolve django. Even the installation fails from pycharm, though it worked fine from windows powershell